# KMP prefix table

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, pattern-matching

I am reading about `KMP` for string matching.
It needs a preprocessing of the pattern by building a prefix table.
For example for the string `ababaca` the prefix table is:  `P = [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1]`
But I am not clear on what does the numbers show. I read that it helps to find matches of the pattern when it shifts but I can not connect this info with the numbers in the table.

Comment: `Prefix Table` in KMP's algorithm is also known as `Partial Match Table`. This blog explains it really beautifully - [The Knuth-Morris-Pratt Algorithm in my own words](http://jakeboxer.com/blog/2009/12/13/the-knuth-morris-pratt-algorithm-in-my-own-words/)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Every number belongs to corresponding prefix ("a", "ab", "aba", ...) and for each prefix it represents length of longest suffix of this string that matches prefix. We do not count whole string as suffix or prefix here, it is called self-suffix and self-prefix (at least in Russian, not sure about English terms).

So we have string "ababaca". Let's look at it. KMP computes Prefix Function for every non-empty prefix. Let's define `s[i]` as the string, `p[i]` as the Prefix function. prefix and suffix may overlap.

```
+---+----------+-------+------------------------+
| i |  s[0:i]  | p[i]  | Matching Prefix/Suffix |
+---+----------+-------+------------------------+
| 0 | a        |     0 |                        |
| 1 | ab       |     0 |                        |
| 2 | aba      |     1 | a                      |
| 3 | abab     |     2 | ab                     |
| 4 | ababa    |     3 | aba                    |
| 5 | ababac   |     0 |                        |
| 6 | ababaca  |     1 | a                      |
|   |          |       |                        |
+---+----------+-------+------------------------+
```

Simple C++ code that computes Prefix function of string S:

```
vector<int> prefixFunction(string s) {
    vector<int> p(s.size());
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < (int)s.size(); i++) {
        while (j > 0 && s[j] != s[i])
            j = p[j-1];

        if (s[j] == s[i])
            j++;
        p[i] = j;
    }   
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer, hope it is better now on. If you still have troubles with KMP, you can choose another algo that fits your needs: Z-Function or Rabin-Karp (with hashing).

Comment: You just helped me understand this entirely and I can write my own version now. Hope you will enjoy my bounty!

Comment: what is the meaning of `j` here, I know it is `p[i]`, an element of the "prefix table", how to understand `s[j]`, and the comparison with `s[i]`

Comment: @http8086 here's a good explanation: https://cp-algorithms.com/string/prefix-function.html

Answer (score 7):

This code may not be the shortest, but easy to understand flow of code.
Simple Java Code for calculating prefix-Array-

```
    String pattern = "ababaca";
    int i = 1, j = 0;
    int[] prefixArray = new int[pattern.length];
    while (i < pattern.length) {

        while (pattern.charAt(i) != pattern.charAt(j) && j > 0) {
            j = prefixArray[j - 1];

        }
        if (pattern.charAt(i) == pattern.charAt(j)) {
            prefixArray[i] = j + 1;
            i++;
            j++;

        } else {
            prefixArray[i] = j;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < prefixArray.length; ++k) {
        System.out.println(prefixArray[k]);
    }
```

It produces the required output-

0
0
1
2
3
0
1

Answer (score 2):

## Python Implementation

```
p='ababaca'

l1 = len(p)

j = 0
i = 1
prefix = [0]

while len(prefix) < l1:
    if p[j] == p[i]:
        prefix.append(j+1)
        i += 1
        j += 1
    else:
        if j == 0:
            prefix.append(0)
            i += 1
        if j != 0:
            j = prefix[j-1]

print prefix
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried my hands using the Javascript, Open for suggestions.

```
const prefixArray = function (p) {
let aux = Array(p.length).fill(0);

// For index 0 the matched index will always be 0, so we will we start from 1
let i = 1;
let m = 0; // mismatched index will be from 0th

// run the loop on pattern length
while ( i < p.length) {

    // 3 Cases here
    // First when we have a match of prefix and suffix of pattern
    if(p.charAt(i) === p.charAt(m)) {
        // increment m
        m++;
        // update aux index
        aux[i] = m;
        // update the index.
        i++;
    } 
    // Now if there is no match and m !=0 means some match happened previously
    // then we need to move back M to that index
    else if(p.charAt(i) !== p.charAt(m) && m !== 0) {
        m = aux[m-1];
        // we dont want to increment I as we want to start comparing this suffix with previous matched
    } else {
        // if none of the above conditions then
        // just update the current index in aux array to 0
        aux[i] = 0; // no match
        i++; // shift to the next char
    }
}

return aux; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### No offset version

This is based on the idea of what I call *todo indexing*:

```
int confix[1000000];

void build_confix(char *pattern) {
    // build len %
    int len_pat = strlen(pattern);
   
    // i, j using todo-indexing.
    int j, i;
    confix[j = 1] = i = 0;

    while (j < strlen(pattern)) {
        whlie (i && pattern[j] != pattern[i])
            // length -> length mapping, no offset
            i = confix[i];
        confix[++j] = pattern[j] == pattern[i]?
            ++i:
              0;
    }
}
```

Then you can use this `confix[]` table to find `needle`s in the middle(`test`)

```
int kmp_find_first(char *test, char *needle) {
    int j = 0, i = 0;
    while (j < strlen(test)) {
        while (i && test[j] != needle[i])
            i = confix[i];
        ++j; test[j] == needle[i]?
            ++i:
              0;
        if (i == strlen(needle))
            return j - strlen(needle);
    }
    return -1;
}
```