# KMP prefix table intuition

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, pattern-matching, knuth-morris-pratt

The main function that builds the failure/prefix table in KMP as I have seen (in all online resources even in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792118/kmp-prefix-table/13792133#comment18969510_13792133)_ is as follows:

```
int j = 0;  
    for (int i = 1; i < pattern.length(); i++) {  
      while (j > 0 && pattern.charAt(j) != pattern.charAt(i)) {   
        j = failure[j - 1];  
      }  
      if (pattern.charAt(j) == pattern.charAt(i)) {   
        j++;   
      }  
      failure[i] = j;  
    }
```

I can't understand this part:
`j = failure[j - 1];`

Why don't we do `j--` instead to go back the string? How do we know that it is correct to update `j` using the failed table?

Comment: Shouldn't you have something like `failure[i]=j;` near the end of that loop (i.e. update the `failure` array)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KMP string matching is correct if the i'th entry of the failure table is the length of the longest suffix-prefix match of the prefix of the pattern of length i.

Notice that if `A[0..k]` is a suffix-prefix match of `A[0..i]`, then `A[0..k]` is either the longest suffix-prefix match of `A[0..i]` or it's a suffix-prefix match of said longest suffix-prefix match.

When you put these two things together, it turns out that we want `failure[i]` to be the length of the longest suffix-prefix match of `pattern[0..i]`.  KMP preprocessing builds `failure` inductively, using the following fact:

If the longest suffix-prefix match of `A[0..i]` is nonempty, chopping off the last character will give some suffix-prefix match of `A[0..i-1]`.

Consequently, the longest suffix-prefix match of `A[0..i]` is either empty or it's formed by extending the longest suffix-prefix match of `A[0..i-1]` by one character or by extending a suffix-prefix match of that longest suffix-prefix match by one character.  The failure function for the preceding characters gives you a straightforward way to iterate over *all* suffix-prefix matches of `pattern[0..i-1]`.

Comment: `or it's a suffix-prefix match of said longest suffix-prefix match.` I don't understand what this sentence means

Comment: Also to build the table we traverse using `j` and `i`. When a mismatch occurs `j` matched so far. So I don't understand why we jump to the previous longest s-f as you say and not just go back char by char

Comment: The suffix-prefix matches of a string are nested.  Every suffix-prefix match of a string can be found by repeatedly finding the longest suffix-prefix match.  The purpose of the `while` loop is to take a suffix-prefix match for `pattern[0..i-1]` whose length is `j` and find a suffix-prefix match for `pattern[0..i-1]` that extends to a suffix-prefix match for `pattern[0..i]`.

Comment: I think I got it.For example in:`acacxababacc` if `j=4` and `i=9` we have `c!=x`.If we did `j--` we would match `c==c` but the suffix length would not be correct

Answer (score 1):

This video really helps to make the intution clear for why we need to do
j = failure[j - 1]; instead of j--;

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWDUjkMv6Lc&feature=emb_logo