# Prefix table for KMP algorithm

Tags: algorithm, string-matching

I am going through KMP algorithm. Even though this algorithm is clear to understand, I have one doubt here.

prefix table algorithm:

```
void prefixTable(char p[], int m){
     int i=1, j=0, F[0] = 0;
     while(i<m){
        if(p[i]==p[j]){
            F[i]=j+1;
            i++;
            j++;
        }else if(j>0){
            j=F[j-1];
        }else{
            F[i]=0;
            i++;
        }
     }
}
```

[image]

As shown in above image step 5, i=5, j=3, j=F[j-1] is executed as j>0 .

why should we take F[j-1]? why can't we use directly F[0]? 
How does it make sure correctness of algorithm?

Comment: The scan is straight out of the book [Data Structures And Algorithms Made Easy](https://www.amazon.in/Data-Structures-Algorithms-Made-Easy-ebook/dp/B01N4OA309?tag=googinhydr18418-21) by Narasiha Karumanchi. It is a wonderful read!

Comment: Related posts - [KMP prefix table](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13792118/465053) & [What is the performance of KMP if the prefix table is all zero?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45276527/465053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

j is the position in the pattern.

if the pattern is processed up to a certain position > 0, then we cannot shift the pattern to the first (0) position if the pattern contains a prefix of itself.

Applied to your example: The pattern is `ababaca`. Try to find it in a text `abababaca`:

- the algorithm will process the text until `ababa|baca` where the pattern is `ababa|c`
- setting j to F[0] = 0, means setting the pattern to `|ababac` which will never match `baca` (note that i will not be changed)
- setting j to F[4] = 3, means setting the pattern to `aba|bac` which will match `baca`
- after the match the pattern is in state `ababac|` and the text in state `abababac|a` and it gets clear that the found pattern is `ab[ababac]a`

Comment: As you explained in 3rd point, why should we use F[j-1] when building prefix function? How does it make sure to get correct position for comparision?

Comment: The KMP-Algorithm es designed never to track back. That means that once reached a position in the text, the pointe will never moved before this position. Consequently the position in the pattern must be adjusted to match the text position. F[i] is computed so that it always contains the right shift to be aligned with the text position.