# Simpler KMP prefix table building. What would be wrong with this implementation?

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

The KMP algorithm needs a prefix table to then know after a failure how many chars it can safely skip. The general idea of the prefix table is that it will tell you for a given pattern `P`, at a given position `i` with a char `C`, how many chars in common the suffix up to `C` has with the prefix of `P`:

```
int[] T = new int[P.length()];
int i = 0;
for (int j = 1; j < P.length(); ++j) {
  if (P.charAt(j) == P.charAt(i)) {
    i++;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
  T[j] = i;
}
```

This is what I came up with. I've looked around and the implementations always seem to be distinct. I've tried toying with a couple of examples (such as ABABACA) but both mine implementation and for instance this [KMP prefix table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13792118/kmp-prefix-table/13792133#13792133) seem to yield the same result.

Could anyone please tell me what is the logic mistake in my implementation and with what kind of inputs would this fail in producing a correct prefix table for the KMP algorithm?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a characteristic of your algorithm that each entry in the table is either 0, or 1 more than the previous entry. So the challenge is to find a string where an entry in the table is less than the previous entry, but not 0.

One such string is "ABACABABC" (which comes from [this wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm#Worked_example_of_the_table-building_algorithm)).

The prefix tables are

```
{0,0,1,0,1,2,3,2,0}  from the linked answer
{0,0,1,0,1,2,3,0,0}  your proposed code
               ^------different here
```

The entries of interest are the 3 followed by a 2.

Consider what happens when 7 characters match. The input string looks like

```
ABACABA?
```

where the ? is the character that didn't match, so the ? is not a B. The `ABA?` could be a match for `ABAC`, so the prefix length is 3.

Now consider what happens when 8 characters match:

```
ABACABAB?
```

where the ? is not a C. In this case `AB?` could match `ABA`, so the prefix length is 2.

This demonstrates that the prefix table *could* have an entry that is less than the previous entry, but not 0.